# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/test-utils'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, mocha.js

Anyone have any idea why as soon as I import this library in my test helper file like so:

```
import jsdom from "jsdom";
import jquery from "jquery";
import ReactTestUtils from "react-dom/test-utils";
```

I immediately get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/test-utils' Require stack:
>
> - /Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/test/test_helper.js
> - /Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/test/components/app_test.js
> - /Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
> - /Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/node_modules/mocha/index.js
> - /Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>   at Object. (/Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/test/test_helper.js:3:1)
>   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
>   at loader (/Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
>   at Object.require.extensions. [as .js] (/Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
>   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>   at Object. (/Users/luiscortes/Projects/auth/client/test/components/app_test.js:1:1)

I am importing just as it says in: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument

This is a legacy React application. Could this be a problem with my version of Mocha?

This my `package.json` file:

```
        "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0-0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jsdom": "^8.5.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "mocha": "^2.3.4",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^4.2.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried `rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json` a dozen times already, the error will not go away.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone working with React 0.14.3 legacy and you are getting this issue, there seems to be no way around it, you need to upgrade to at least react 15.0.1